# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

I have an installation of SQL Server 2008 R2.

In the subscriptions section I do not see an icon or button to create data driven subscriptions; in the previous installation of SQL Server 2008, I do see this option.

Can anyone tell me where I can create data driven subscriptions?

Comment: have you ensured that you have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Are you running Enterprise Edition? It's required for data-driven subs IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Data Driven Subscriptions is a feature that is only available in SQL Developer or Enterprise Edition.